# VS Code в связке с С++ (windows)

Tags: c++, настройка, visual-studio-code

Помогите **запустить** (то есть собрать (**build**) и отладить) код с++ в vsCode на windows 10. У меня уже установлен VS Community 2017 и расширение С/С++. 
Часто приходиться открывать однофайловые программы. Именно для этого хочу использовать VS Code. 
Возможность дебага не важна, но если есть возможность, то скажите.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"Hello World!";
}
```

Что у меня уже получается. С помощью [этой](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/cc-extension-for-visual-studio-code/) инструкции я могу собрать проект.
Для этого:
 1. Установить плагин и перезагрузить программу
 2. Открываю VSCode.
 3. "Файл-Открыть папку" и выбираю папку где находится код
 4. В папке с вашим кодом создаем файл: `build.bat`, куда вставляем этот код:

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
set compilerflags=/Od /Zi /EHsc
set linkerflags=/OUT:hello.exe
cl.exe %compilerflags% replay.cpp /link %linkerflags%
```

5. В папке открываю файл с кодом и нажимаю ctrl+shift+B
 6. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 7. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 8. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 9. В открытой папке появляется папка ".vscode" а в ней "tasks.json"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 10. В место этого вставляем это:

```
{
   "version": "0.1.0",
    "windows": {
        "command": "build.bat",
        "isShellCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always"
    }
}
```

11. Нажимаем опять ctrl+shift+B и видим что создался файл hello.exe и другие.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот процесс можно как то автоматизировать? Еще в bat-файле можно как то передавать имя cpp-файла, что бы exe был с таким же именем? Что у меня не так с кодировкой может кто знает? И я не могу запустить отладку.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы при щелчке на cpp-файле вызывался vsCode? или что вы хотите? Ваш вопрос непонятен...

Answer (score 2):

Если я все понял правильно, то хочется простой вещи - уметь открыть файл с с++ кодом (простенький хелло-ворд) и уметь скомпилить-запустить одной кнопкой (мне это также хотелось и vscode предоставляет такую возможность легко сделать в линуксе, но не в винде).

Я нашел следующий способ.

- Установить расширение [CodeRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)
- Теперь плугин нужно настроить. Открываем настройки (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) и ищем секцию "code-runner.executorMap", напротив ее нажимаем карандашик и справа в окно копируется кусок json с настройками. Там ищем для нашего расширения (cpp) и видим там для gcc. Меняем на такую строку
  `"cpp": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build\\vcvars64.bat\" && cd $dir && cl $fileName /Fe$fileNameWithoutExt.exe && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt.exe"`
- готово

В строке в самом начале запускается батник, который настраивает окрущение для компилятора. Возможно, Нужно  будет его поискать самостоятельно и подменить путь/имя (а это точно нужно  будет сделать, если винда 32битная к примеру)

Все, теперь достаточно открыть с++ файл и сверху справа есть треугольник для компиляции-запуска.

Отладку можно попробовать настроить, но я до этого не дошел (под линуксом все работает:) ).